# Determine the maximum value of $f(x,y,z) = (xyz)^{(1/3)}$ given that x, y, and z are non-negative numbers that satisfy $x+y+z =1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Is Lagrange multipliers in this question appropriate? I don't really know how to begin solving this question..

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a self-contained statement of the problem you want help with.   The title was barely sufficient for the purpose here, and attempts to rely solely on the title to describe the setup and goal most often fall short, risking a disconnect between what the title and the body convey.

Comment: $f(x,y,z)$ is maximized precisely when  $xyz$ is maximized. The power makes the argument unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Since AM $\geq$ GM,

$\frac{x+y+z}{3} \geq (xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Therefore

$(xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}} \leq \frac{1}{3}$

Alternatively you can do the following:

Let $f(x, y, z) = (xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}} + \lambda (x+y+z -1)$

Set $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0$

Simplifying,

$x = y = z = \frac{1}{3}$

Hence the maximum value of $(xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is $\left( \left(\frac{1}{3} \right)^3 \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{3}$

One difficulty in this case is checking the second order condition. You'll have to compute the [Bordered Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian) matrix. More specifically, in this case, you will find the details [here](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~clark/285/2006-07/handouts/lagrange-2deriv.pdf), Theorem $5$, page $6$. If you compute everything properly, you'll find that $-\text{det}(H_4) = 3 > 0$ and $-\text{det}(H_3) = -2 < 0$ and hence this is a local maximum.

Comment: @hardmath Fixed. Thanks a lot for pointing out.

Comment: Alternatively we can compare to values on the boundary, as in a compact (closed, bounded) domain the maximum occurs either at a  critical point or on the boundary.